# Nested template (C++17) compilation fails on VS19

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, variadic-templates

Code:

(Note that template is not instantiated - that's not a mistake, compilation fails even without it)
main.cpp:

```
namespace mylib {
    template<typename ...Params>
    class SomeClass {
        public:
            template<typename ...NestedParams>
            class NestedClass {
            };

            template<typename ...NestedParams>
            NestedClass<NestedParams...> createNestedInstance();
    };
}

template<typename... Params>
template<typename... NestedParams>
typename mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::template NestedClass<NestedParams...>
mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::createNestedInstance() {
    return SomeClass::NestedClass<NestedParams...>();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(msvc_exploit001)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(msvc_exploit001 main.cpp)
```

**GCC (Msys64 MinGW64)**:
compiles without warnings

**Visual Studio Comminity 2019:**

```
msvc_exploit001.cpp(25): error C2244: 'mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::createNestedInstance': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
msvc_exploit001.cpp(25): note: see declaration of 'mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::createNestedInstance'
msvc_exploit001.cpp(25): note: definition
msvc_exploit001.cpp(25): note: 'mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::NestedClass<NestedParams...> mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::createNestedInstance(void)'
msvc_exploit001.cpp(25): note: existing declarations
msvc_exploit001.cpp(25): note: 'mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::NestedClass<NestedParams...> mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::createNestedInstance(void)'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1427~1.291\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Printed by MSVC error contains identical signatures for both declaration and definition, but it insists that they do not match.

I'm compiling on Windows 10, using CMake (CLion) and default compiler options (only specifying C++17 standard level)

Comment: can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you still get a compilation error if you remove the unneeded explicit `SomeClass::` from the `createdNestedInstance` method declaration?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, there still error without it. (actually it was initially without it - I added it later). removed it in sources

Comment: I posted all necessary code and specified what compilers and options I use. please clarify what is missing to fit minimal reproducible example criterias? 

added CMakeLists.txt in hope it will make issue more clear.

Comment: No you didn't You only post the template. Not how you instantiate it. We need to be able to reproduce your issue. If you put this in main.cpp, it says "missing entry point" or "undefined reference to `main'".

Comment: @JHBonarius just because this issue is reproduced without instantiation. Replaced `add_executable` with `add_library` for perfect match.

Comment: I opened [an issue at MS](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/C-Compiler-error-on-dependent-templa/1338656)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems msvc has issues with the `template`. This compiles

```
namespace mylib {
    template<typename ...Params>
    class SomeClass {
        public:
            template<typename ...NestedParams>
            class NestedClass {
            };

            template<typename ...NestedParams>
            NestedClass<NestedParams...> createNestedInstance();
    };
}

template<typename... Params>
template<typename... NestedParams>
typename mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::NestedClass<NestedParams...>
mylib::SomeClass<Params...>::createNestedInstance() {
    return SomeClass::NestedClass<NestedParams...>();
}

int main() {
    auto sc = mylib::SomeClass<int, bool>();
    auto c = sc.createNestedInstance<float, double>();
}
```

As stated in the comments, the template might be required by the standard.  In that case,  maybe you should file a bug report at Microsoft.

Comment: what compiler do you use?

Comment: @kkolyan Visual Studio 2015 14.0

Comment: That `template` keyword is required by the Standard. But yes, erasing it does get MSVC to accept the code (and clang++ to reject it).